# NHibernate connection.isolation settings is not used while establishing a connection to the database

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have created a .net application, which using NHibernate 2.1.0.4000 to connect with SQL server and the configuration is given as below.

```
<nhibernate xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=(local);database=MYDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <!-- Specifying the default schema improves the query execution plan generated by SQL server -->
      <property name="default_schema">dbo</property>
      <property name="connection.isolation">ReadUncommitted</property>
      <!-- Specifying the 2nd level cache -->
      <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache</property>
      <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
      <property name="cache.use_query_cache" >true</property>
      <mapping assembly="MyAssemply" />
    </session-factory>
  </nhibernate>
```

In Nhibernate configuration, the isolation level is specified as `ReadUncommitted`. But isolation level is not used while establishing a connection to the database. Instead it’s taking the default isolation level as `ReadCommitted` to proceed.
Doing some investigation its observed that if `session.BeginTransaction()` is specified in the code then isolation level is taken as the configured value. Is there any way to connect database with isolation level as “ReadUncommitted” (or isolation level from the settings) without setting `session.BeginTransaction()`.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct.

Transaction isolation levels are set when starting the transaction. Which is consistent with the recommendation that you do all of your work inside explicit transactions.